# 05 Civic losing power shortly after take off every time I start the car when warm.

Tags: engine, stall, power-loss

It doesn't do it on the first cold start but as soon as the engine is warm I start it up and a few seconds into driving it bogs down feels like its lost all power and then shortly after you can see the rpms go up and it gets life again. Just replaced two of the coils cause they looked damaged slightly and dbII reading says nothing. Otherwise only 125k km on the engine....

Comment: Is this every time you accelerate when the engine is warm, or only the first time after you start it?